# Create-react-app vs custom Webpack config for publishing react app to npm repository

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app, npm-publish

**Scenario 1 -** Using create-react-app I'm able to successfully develop a SPA and deploy it on several platforms like - githubpages, netlify heroku etc. Here create-react-app does all the configuration work I believe and minimal effort from my side. Rather, I'm able to focus more on the logic rather than configuration.

**Scenario 2 -** Now I'm using same create-react-app and built a custom count-down-timer app using react-hooks. I see it working successfully in local and with npm publish and signing up in npm site, I published it to public usage. For some reason, it is not working as expected.

**Question -** What is the preferred way to create react applications if I wanted to publish it on npm repo? What is the standard/best known configuration for it?

I reached here after some basic failed research. Any pointers can be helpful.